# GCP datastore cursor is the same

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am doing pagination with Flask and GCP Datastore, but I have an issue with the cursor when I click to the next page, the cursor is still the same when I click to the other pages. For example, when I click on page 10 from page 9, because the cursor is still the same, it still displays the same content from page 9. How can I solve this problem thanks? Here is my code.

```
@bp.route('/selectimage/<dataset_name>/<dataset_id>/<startdate>/<enddate>/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def selectimage(dataset_id, dataset_name, startdate, enddate):
    photo = {}
    startdate = int(startdate)
    enddate = int(enddate)
    dataset_id = dataset_id
    dataset_name = dataset_name

    request_arg = request.args
    if "page" in request_arg:
        total_row = request_arg.get('total_row')
        page = request_arg.get('page')
        total_page = request_arg.get('total_page')
        total_page_range = range(0, int(total_page))
        if page == '1':
            # get result
            photometa_data_results = datastore_client.query(kind='photometadata')

            photometa_data_results.add_filter('Time', '>=', startdate)
            photometa_data_results.add_filter('Time', '<=', enddate)
            photometa_data_results.order = ['-Time']  # order by time
            photometa_data_results = photometa_data_results.fetch(limit=40)
            result = list(next(photometa_data_results.pages))
        else:
            page_limit = (int(page) - 1) * 40

            # get first cursor
            query_photometa_data_cursor = datastore_client.query(
                kind='photometadata')  # query photometadata grap by instagram

            query_photometa_data_cursor.add_filter('Time', '>=', startdate)
            query_photometa_data_cursor.add_filter('Time', '<=', enddate)
            query_photometa_data_cursor.order = ['-Time']  # order by time
            photometa_data_results_cursor_1 = query_photometa_data_cursor.fetch(start_cursor=None,
                                                                                limit=360)  # result of query photometadata table
            photometa_data_results_page = next(photometa_data_results_cursor_1.pages)
            photometa_data_results_cursor = photometa_data_results_cursor_1.next_page_token

            # get result
            photometa_data_results = datastore_client.query(kind='photometadata')
            print(photometa_data_results_cursor)
            photometa_data_results.add_filter('Time', '>=', startdate)
            photometa_data_results.add_filter('Time', '<=', enddate)
            photometa_data_results.order = ['-Time']  # order by time
            photometa_data_results = photometa_data_results.fetch(start_cursor=photometa_data_results_cursor, limit=40)
            result = list(next(photometa_data_results.pages))
            print(result)

    else:
        page = 1
        # get how many pages
        photometa_data_pages = datastore_client.query(kind='photometadata')

        photometa_data_pages.add_filter('Time', '>=', startdate)
        photometa_data_pages.add_filter('Time', '<=', enddate)
        photometa_data_pages.order = ['-Time']  # order by time

        photometa_data_pages_result = list(photometa_data_pages.fetch())
        total_row = (len(photometa_data_pages_result))
        total_page = math.ceil(len(photometa_data_pages_result) / 40)
        total_page_range = range(0, total_page)

        # get_result
        photometa_data = datastore_client.query(kind='photometadata')

        photometa_data.add_filter('Time', '>=', startdate)

        photometa_data.add_filter('Time', '<=', enddate)
        photometa_data.order = ['-Time']  # order by time

        photoinfo = photometa_data.fetch(limit=40)
        result = list(next(photoinfo.pages))
        next_cursor = photoinfo.next_page_token

    query_dataset_photo = datastore_client.query(kind='Datasetphotos')  # query dataset photo table
    query_dataset_photo.add_filter('Dataset_id', '=', dataset_id)
    query_dataset_photo_list_result = list(query_dataset_photo.fetch())  # list query result
    dataset_photo_namelist = []

    if query_dataset_photo_list_result != []:
        for dataset_photo_filename in query_dataset_photo_list_result:
            dataset_photo_namelist.append(dataset_photo_filename['Filename'])

    if result == []:
        flash('No photo', category='info')
    else:
        for results in result:
            time = datetime.fromtimestamp(results['Time'])
            photo[results['Filename']] = {'Filename': results['Filename'], "Url": results['Gcs_public_url'],
                                          "Time": time,
                                          'Link': results["Link"]}
    totoalphoto = len(photo)
    # get the ticked photo
    upload_data_list = []
    check_name_list = []
    if request.form.getlist('images'):
        images = request.form.getlist('images')  # get the image from ticked form
        for image in images:
            querys = datastore_client.query(kind='photometadata')
            querys.add_filter('Filename', '=', image)
            datas = list(querys.fetch())
            for data in datas:
                name = dataset_id + ':' + data['Filename']
                if data['Filename'] in check_name_list:
                    pass
                else:
                    upload_datas = {
                        'Filename': data['Filename'],
                        "PostID": data['PostID'],
                        "Storage_url": data['Storage_url'],
                        "Gcs_public_url": data['Gcs_public_url'],
                        "Url": data['Url'],
                        'Dataset_id': dataset_id,
                        'Link': data['Link'],
                        "Time": data['Time'],
                        'Upload_date': datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),
                    }
                    check_name_list.append(data['Filename'])
                    upload_data_list.append(upload_datas)

        upload_data_lists = [upload_data_list[i:i + 499] for i in
                             range(0, len(upload_data_list), 499)]
        for upload_data_list in upload_data_lists:
            batch = datastore_client.batch()
            kind = 'evaluation_dataset_photo'
            batch.begin()
            for upload_data in upload_data_list:
                name = upload_data['check_name']
                data_key = datastore_client.key(kind, name)
                task = datastore.Entity(key=data_key, exclude_from_indexes=['Url', 'Gcs_public_url'])
                task.update(upload_data)
                batch.put(task)
            batch.commit()

        number = len(images)  # number of upload photo
        message = 'Uploaded ' + str(number) + ' photo to ' + dataset_name  # number of photo upload
        flash(message, category='success')
        logging.info(message)
        return redirect('/selectimage/{}/{}/{}/{}/{}'.format(dataset_name, dataset_id, startdate, enddate))
    return render_template('selectimage.html', dataset_name=dataset_name, photo=photo,
                           totoalphoto=totoalphoto, page=page, total_page_range=total_page_range,
                           total_page_range_count=total_page
                           , total_row=total_row, dataset_id=dataset_id, startdate=startdate, enddate=enddate)
```

frontend code

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block scripts %}
    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='flask.css') }}">
    {{ super() }}
{% endblock %}
{% block app_content %}
    <div class="page-header" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
        <h1>Add image</h1>
        <b><h1>Dataset:{{ dataset_name }} Photo:{{ total_row }}</h1></b>

        <div class="col-md-2" id="client-paginator">
            <ul class="pagination">
                {% for total_pages in total_page_range %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="/selectimage/{{ dataset_name }}/{{ dataset_id }}/{{ startdate }}/{{ enddate }}?page={{ total_pages + 1 }}&total_page={{ total_page_range_count }}&total_row={{ total_row }}">
                            {{ total_pages + 1 }}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


    {% if photo != {} %}
        <form id='assignimage' action="" method="POST">
            <div align="left"><input style="heightx: 15%;width: 15%" class="btn-success" type="submit" value="Add">
            </div>
            {% for k,v in photo.items() %}
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img src="{{ v['Url'] }}" style="display:block; margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto"
                         width="330px" height="330px">
                    <div style="margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;width: 20em;text-align: center">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="images" value="{{ v['Filename'] }}">
                        {{ v['Time'] }}
                        <a href="{{ v['Link'] }}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window" target="_blank"></a></div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </form>

        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended by Google the usage of cursors instead of integer offsets, because of the read operations that are being made by the client library, and I quote:

> Although Datastore mode databases support integer offsets, you should
> avoid using them. Instead, use cursors. Using an offset only avoids
> returning the skipped entities to your application, but these entities
> are still retrieved internally. The skipped entities do affect the
> latency of the query, and your application is billed for the read
> operations required to retrieve them. Using cursors instead of offsets
> lets you avoid all these costs.

I'd recommend you to be careful on how you are setting the cursor and what info is passed (I'd suggest you to debug and test the code that is quoted below )

> Be careful when passing a cursor to a client, such as in a web form.
> Although the client cannot change the cursor value to access results
> outside of the original query, it is possible for it to decode the
> cursor to expose information about result entities, such as the
> project ID, entity kind, key name or numeric ID, ancestor keys, and
> properties used in the query's filters and sort orders. If you don't
> want users to have access to that information, you can encrypt the
> cursor, or store it and provide the user with an opaque key.

what I think is causing you problems with your implementation

Now talking about the implementation of this using cursors, there is a small snippet at the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#cursors_limits_and_offsets) or if yo prefer to take a look to this at the official [github repo, you can go here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/4b91143f8848e0df40955163ad851603dd12e70a/datastore/cloud-client/snippets.py#L363-L372)

```
def cursor_paging(client):
    # [START datastore_cursor_paging]

    def get_one_page_of_tasks(cursor=None):
        query = client.query(kind='Task')
        query_iter = query.fetch(start_cursor=cursor, limit=5)
        page = next(query_iter.pages)

        tasks = list(page)
        next_cursor = query_iter.next_page_token

        return tasks, next_cursor
    # [END datastore_cursor_paging]

    page_one, cursor_one = get_one_page_of_tasks()
    page_two, cursor_two = get_one_page_of_tasks(cursor=cursor_one)
    return page_one, cursor_one, page_two, cursor_two
```